# Python Error : int has no attribute "append"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
count = 999999
my_list = 0
while count >= 0:
    if str(count) == str(count)[::-1]:
        count = int(count)
        my_list.append(count)
for i in range(999, 100, -1):
    for j in range(999, 100, -1):
        for k in my_list:
            if k == i*j:
                print(k)
                break
```

This is my code for Project Euler 4- I keep getting the error

> int has no attribute "append".

I can't see what's wrong with it. I have only learnt basic Python anyway- and I also feel this brute force method is inefficient.

Comment: `my_list` is an `int`; those do not have an append method; `list`s do. did you mean `my_list = []`?

Comment: `my_list` is a `int`, not a list. You can't append to a int.

Comment: oh thanks a lot now I get it rip that was silly.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call an `append` method on an `int` type. This causes the error.

Use this to make `my_list` a list instead of an integer

```
my_list =[0]
```